# Limit access to form to authenticated users?

Tags: forms, anonymous-user

We're using Drupal8+CiviCRM

We have a data entry form (created with a profile) that we don't want Anonymous users to access. We also have several other forms that we do want Anonymous access for (donations, email subscribes).

How can I limit access to just one form?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the profile settings page, there's a collapsed advanced section. There you can limit it to a group.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Drupal webform_civicrm module which gives you fine grained control on who can access the forms.